# Difference between package.json dependencies and published dependencies?

Tags: npm, dependencies, package.json

When looking at a package published on npm, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router, and looking at the `package.json` for the same version in the source, there is a vast difference in dependencies. For the example react-router, the webpage lists 10 dependencies and the package.json 27.

My assumption is that package.json is the source of truth, so why is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking in the wrong package.json. react-router is a monorepo, so it contains multiple packages inside one repo and you were looking in the wrong package.json. If you look to [this one](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/package.json), you would see that number of dependencies match npmjs.com

Comment: `@lazyd3v` is correct. you're looking at the wrong _package.json_. However, the more link accurate link is [this one](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v5.1.2/packages/react-router/package.json) because it points to the `5.1.2` tagged version of the repo (not the _Master_). The current latest semver of `react-router` in the npm registry is `5.1.2`. There's some minor differences between the two links - e.g. the link that I provided shows the authors as _"Michael Jackson"_ and _"Ryan Florence"_ which matches the result of running `npm show react-router authors` via your CLI.